# One users table for cakephp 1.3 and 2.x apps?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

As the title says, I have 2 different cakePHP apps, but the users of both are the same. I would like for there to be one login/pass for both applications, but i'm not sure how to go about doing that. When they log into one, if they log into the other in the same browser different tab, it logs out the other. Would I use Cookies? Is it possible to just tell the cake 2.x app to decrypt or whatever the password the same way the 1.3 app does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added the hash function to your user's model. They removed auto hashing in 2.x to make it more flexible. 
Something like this in your 2.x user.php model file...

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
    return true;
}
```

Help yourself debug your issue by adding `pr($this->data);` in your appController `beforeFilter()` then attempt login and compare the username and passwords that are being requested in each app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another Database config in `/config/database.php`

And in the `UserModel` add the `useDbConfig` attribute.

See [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usedbconfig) for more info

EDIT:

The `Security.salt` setting in `/config/core.php` should be the same for both apps:
`Configure::write('Security.salt', 'same for app A as for app B');`

Comment: I already setup the Database config file. The cake 2.x app can access the users table for the 1.3 app, but it doesn't validate correctly? Even with the correct user login. I want both apps to use the same login.

Comment: They still aren't matching up. The 1.3 created user password starts as 5546e, but when I try using that login in the 2.x app, it shows the password starting as 5984e. There doesn't appear to be an encryption specified anywhere else either.

Comment: Is there some way to see/compare the hashing between the two apps? Or do something like http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html for cake 2.x?

Comment: You need to use the salt from the app which has created the users. Have you tried to create a new user and then login with both apps?